# Preciso fazer uma forma com css e não consigo. E rotation não funciona no IE11

Tags: html, html5, css3, div, css-animations

Fala galera, tudo bem com vocês? (Espero e desejo que sim)

Estou começando um novo [projeto pessoal](http://hb1virtual.com.br/Grafica/graf.html), e estou apanhando pra caramba com duas questões:

1 - O conjunto de menus é rotativo, enquanto a logo central fica parada e somente roda na função hover, só que infelizmente os botões do menu não quer rodar no IE11, tentei no Windows 7 e 10. Nos demais navegadores tá normal.

2 - Queria fazer uma faixa no topo sem usar imagem, apenas mudando a forma das div's, como geralmente o pessoal faz retângulos, em último caso eu uso png, mas estou preferindo apenas usar div com background. Segue uma imagem do que pretendo:
[image: Boneca Topo do Site HB1 Virtual]

Segue meus códigos:

```css
@charset "utf-8";

body {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 92%;
 max-width: 960px;
 background: url('../images/bg.png');
 background-attachment: fixed;
}
.menutopo {
 width: 100%;
 height: 200px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.menu {
 position: relative;
 left: 50%;
 top: 50%;
 width: 240px;
 height: 240px;
 margin-left:-120px;
 margin-top:-120px;
}
.faixas {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 240px;
 background: #BB0F12;
}
.marquee{
 display: block;
 position: fixed;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 240px;
 height: 240px;
 animation: scroll 10s linear infinite;
 -webkit-animation:spin 20s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation:spin 20s linear infinite;
    animation:spin 20s linear infinite;
 -webkit-animation-direction: reverse; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-direction: reverse;
}
@-moz-keyframes spin { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(-360deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg); } }
@keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg); transform:rotate(-360deg); } }
.marquee:hover {
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
.menuse {
 position: fixed;
 background: url('../images/botaoprincipal01120.png') no-repeat;
 width: 120px;
 height: 120px;
}
.menuse:hover {
 background: url('../images/botaoprincipal01hover120.png') no-repeat;
}
.menusd {
 position: fixed;
 margin-left: 120px;
 background: url('../images/botaoprincipal02120.png') no-repeat;
 width: 120px;
 height: 120px;
}
.menusd:hover {
 background: url('../images/botaoprincipal02hover120.png') no-repeat;
}
.menuie {
 margin-top: 120px;
 position: fixed;
 background: url('../images/botaoprincipal03120.png') no-repeat;
 width: 120px;
 height: 120px;
}
.menuie:hover {
 background: url('../images/botaoprincipal03hover120.png') no-repeat;
}
.menuid {
 position: fixed;
 margin-top: 120px;
 margin-left: 120px;
 background: url('../images/botaoprincipal04120.png') no-repeat;
 width: 120px;
 height: 120px;
}
.menuid:hover {
 background: url('../images/botaoprincipal04hover120.png') no-repeat;
}
.menulogo {
 float: none;
 position: fixed;
 width: 160px;
 height: 160px;
 margin-top: 40px;
 margin-left: 40px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background: url('../images/logoprincipal160.png') no-repeat;
 transition: 0.70s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.70s;
  -moz-transition: 0.70s;
  -ms-transition: 0.70s;
  -o-transition: 0.70s;
}
.menulogo:hover {
 transition: 0.70s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.70s;
  -moz-transition: 0.70s;
  -ms-transition: 0.70s;
  -o-transition: 0.70s;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
.clear { clear: both; }
.lateralesquerda {
 position: absolute;
 float: left;
 color: white;
 background-color: black;
 width: 150px;
 margin-top: 150px;
 border: solid;
}
.lateraldireita {
 position: relative;
 float: right;
 color: white;
 background-color: black;
 width: 150px;
 margin-top: 150px;
 border: solid;
}

.banner {
 width: 600px;
 color: white;
 float:right;
 position:fixed;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Virtual Serviços - TESTE</title>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/favicon.png" />
<link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="images/favicon.ico"/>
<link href="css/graf.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<br>
<div class="menutopo">
 <div class="faixas">
  <div class="menu">
   <div class="marquee">
    <a href="../index.html"><div class="menuse"></div></a>
    <a href="../index.html"><div class="menusd"></div></a>
    <a href="../index.html"><div class="menuie"></div></a>
    <a href="../index.html"><div class="menuid"></div></a>
   </div> <!--marquee-->
   <a href="../index.html"><div class="menulogo"></div></a>
  </div>
 </div> <!--menu-->
</div> <!--menutopo-->
</body>
</html>
```

Caso queiram, deixei um arquivo RAR para baixarem, caso seja necessário, no meu domínio:
[Arquivos para download](http://hb1virtual.com.br/Grafica/ajuda_nois.rar)

Comment: Cara dei uma editada por completo na resposta, acho que agora resolve todos os pontos. Qualquer dúvida comenta lá que te dou um help no que precisar.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>**EDIT:** *Preferi reformular a resposta por completo depois de analisar o código direto no link citado na pergunta*</sup>

Vendo o código percebi alguns erros. Primeiro seu @keyframes estava vom um problema de vendo prefix vc colocou -webkt- dentro de um @keyfremes que não deviria ter-lo

```
@keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg); transform:rotate(-360deg); } }
```

Depois, parece que o IE não conseguiu rotacionar o elemento que tem p`osition: fixed;` então alterei por `position: absolute;` e ficou perfeito sem problemas com a animação nem com o posicionamento.

Depois disso foi a vez de fazer a faixa no topo. Para fazer usei um radial-gradiente com a cor do meio transparente, e valor fixo de "raio" para não ter problemas em telas menores.

Veja a imagem rodando no IE11 :D

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o resultado referente a imagem acima:

**OBS:** Não mexi em nada no HTML

```css
@charset "utf-8";

body {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 92%;
 max-width: 960px;
 /* background: url('../images/bg.png'); */
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, black, silver);
 background-attachment: fixed;
}
.menutopo {
 width: 100%;
 height: 200px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.menu {
 position: relative;
 left: 50%;
 top: 50%;
 width: 240px;
 height: 240px;
 margin-left:-120px;
 margin-top:-120px;
}
.faixas {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 240px;
 /* background: #BB0F12; */
  overflow: hidden;
}
.faixas::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at center 100%, transparent 140px, red 140px);
}
.marquee{
 display: block;
 /* position: fixed; */
  border-radius: 50%;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 240px;
 height: 240px;
 animation: scroll 10s linear infinite;
 -webkit-animation:spin 20s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation:spin 20s linear infinite;
    animation:spin 20s linear infinite;
 -webkit-animation-direction: reverse; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-direction: reverse;
}
@-moz-keyframes spin { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(-360deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg); } }
@keyframes spin { 100% { transform:rotate(-360deg); } }
.marquee:hover {
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
.menuse {
 position: absolute;
 background: url(https://placecage.com/120/120) no-repeat;
 width: 120px;
 height: 120px;
}
.menuse:hover {
 background: url('../images/botaoprincipal01hover120.png') no-repeat;
}
.menusd {
 position: absolute;
 margin-left: 120px;
 background: blue;
 width: 120px;
 height: 120px;
}
.menusd:hover {
 background: url('../images/botaoprincipal02hover120.png') no-repeat;
}
.menuie {
 margin-top: 120px;
 position: absolute;
 background: yellow;
 width: 120px;
 height: 120px;
}
.menuie:hover {
 background: url('../images/botaoprincipal03hover120.png') no-repeat;
}
.menuid {
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: 120px;
 margin-left: 120px;
 background: green;
 width: 120px;
 height: 120px;
}
.menuid:hover {
 background: url('../images/botaoprincipal04hover120.png') no-repeat;
}
.menulogo {
 float: none;
 position: fixed;
 width: 160px;
 height: 160px;
 margin-top: 40px;
 margin-left: 40px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background: url('../images/logoprincipal160.png') no-repeat;
 transition: 0.70s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.70s;
  -moz-transition: 0.70s;
  -ms-transition: 0.70s;
  -o-transition: 0.70s;
}
.menulogo:hover {
 transition: 0.70s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.70s;
  -moz-transition: 0.70s;
  -ms-transition: 0.70s;
  -o-transition: 0.70s;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
.clear { clear: both; }
.lateralesquerda {
 position: absolute;
 float: left;
 color: white;
 background-color: black;
 width: 150px;
 margin-top: 150px;
 border: solid;
}
.lateraldireita {
 position: relative;
 float: right;
 color: white;
 background-color: black;
 width: 150px;
 margin-top: 150px;
 border: solid;
}

.banner {
 width: 600px;
 color: white;
 float:right;
 position:fixed;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="menutopo">
 <div class="faixas">
  <div class="menu">
   <div class="marquee">
    <a href="../index.html"><div class="menuse"></div></a>
    <a href="../index.html"><div class="menusd"></div></a>
    <a href="../index.html"><div class="menuie"></div></a>
    <a href="../index.html"><div class="menuid"></div></a>
   </div> <!--marquee-->
   <a href="../index.html"><div class="menulogo"></div></a>
  </div>
 </div> <!--menu-->
</div> <!--menutopo-->
```